# Getting data from controller to partial via composer in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Apologies for yet another first app question.  My situation is that I have a form on one page which submits data to a controller.  That controller runs a query and spits the results out to a view as such...

```
return view('ingate', ['issuers' => $issuer]);
```

In the view I am able to loop through $issuer in a blade @foreach loop with no problem, so the view itself is fine.  From the view I call a partial...

```
@include('over', array('issuers' => $issuers))
```

I have a composer for the 'over' partial, that is registered in my service provider as

```
`view()->composer('over', 'App\Http\Composers\OverComposer');
```

The problem is that in the composer I need to access a value in the $issuers array and run a query from that value before returning the view.  I've tried about two dozen different ways of accessing the contents of $issuers, but I end up with either undefined variable errors or offset errors.  I'm sort of at a loss as to how to access $issuers in that composer.  Any help would be appreciated.
`

Comment: Do you want using a logic partial of controller in `View`. This is bad practice. I think you should preprocess data by foreach in controller before you assign to view

Comment: I would like to process the data in the composer, not the view, and simply return a common old array to the partial.  But I need to be able to access an element of the array that was originally passed to the view in order to process the partial in the composer.

Comment: View Composers are recommended for static (assume constant) data i.e. data which remains fairly constant and is required every time the view (partial) is used like for example Menu or Navigation view.

Comment: For any kind of dynamic data as @Kelvin has suggested you should construct the data in the controller and then pass it to the view.

Comment: Just before the view is rendered, the composer's `compose` method is called with the `Illuminate\View\View` instance. You may use the `with` method to bind data to the view.

Comment: So if one has a View that requires what is essentially a list of lists, where each list is derived from a separate query, one should chuck 20 or so queries into one  controller method and return the view with 20 different arrays?

Comment: @Jilson: My problem is not binding the data back to the view from the composer, it is in accessing data from the view that called the composer.

Comment: @BlindFish you can use multi-level array and in `view` you use foreach in foreach

Comment: I feel like I am failing to properly explain this situation and that is my fault.  My end result would look similar to this http://www.baseball-reference.com/players/a/aaronha01.shtml  Where each table is a separate query.  Even if I lump everything into one multi-level array that's still 20+ queries in one controller method, which, I don't know, is that really how you would do it?

Comment: Can you post your `OverComposer` ?

Comment: What you are aiming for is probably possible. If you look at the venfor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php the function definition of if(!function_exists('view')){function view($view = null, $data=[], $mergedData=[])} suggests that there may be an option to merge dynamic data. Will try out and let you know if I succeed.

Comment: I guess you want to pass data back to the composer not to controller from a view if i get you.

Comment: @oseintow: I am sending an array from controller to view.  The array is accessible in the view.  I am calling a partial from the view, and would like to access that array in the composer for that partial.

Comment: @Jilson: After so many failed attempts I've pretty much wiped the composer except for a simple attempt to declare the array variable and the do a data dump in the construct() method.  There is nothing in compose() as of yet.

Comment: Have not tried that before tho but i guess the only way that i can think of it is to store the array in a session then access the session in the composer

Comment: This is where it sucks being an old, lol.  I formed my habits before PhP was even Object Oriented.  In my mind it should be a simple task to display the results of multiple queries on the same page.  I'm just really struggling to get my head around how to do that within the Laravel framework.